# CakePHP, injects "LEFT JOIN" (mentioning fields in an associated model) into my update attempts

Tags: mysql, cakephp, mysql-error-1054

This is driving me crazy, I am trying to do something like:

```
$this->data = $this->Prox->read('proxy',$currentgetdata); 
                    $this->data['Prox']['checked'] = 2;
                    $this->Prox->save();
```

where I have a model association of:

```
class Prox extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Prox';
    var $primaryKey = 'id';
    ######## Define Model Associations #########
    var $belongsTo = array('Proxylink' => array('className' => 'Proxylink'));
}
```

But I get an error of:

```
SELECT `Prox`.`proxy` FROM `proxes` AS `Prox` LEFT JOIN `proxylinks` AS `Proxylink` ON (`Prox`.`proxylink_id` = `Proxylink`.`id`) WHERE `Prox`.`id` = '58.22.101.239:808' LIMIT 1

1054: Unknown column 'Prox.proxylink_id' in 'on clause'
```

I don't get why its putting this into the query "LEFT JOIN `proxylinks` AS `Proxylink` ON (`Prox`.`proxylink_id` = `Proxylink`.`id`)" and I have been unable to find any documentation on why its doing this, its as if it HAS to try to include a non-existant hybrid of a field from my associated model and my current model on each query, which I find extremely bizarre.. any advice is appreciated on what I can do to get my save / update queries to work.

Comment: Have you tried calling `$this->Prox->save($this->data)` instead?

Comment: I just tried that and still get the same error, I also tried this using updateAll but I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [belongsTo](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1042/belongsTo) association your 'prox' table must have 'proxylink_id' field.

If you don't want associative models to be joined you must set '[recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/view/439/recursive)' option to `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the solution (set recursive to -1), however the cookbook doesn't give any example for how to implement this, I'm assuming that I just put it into an array somehow, if anyone has an example I would very much appreciate it.. thanks

Comment: `$this->Prox->recursive = -1;` in your controller before query. Another way to set `recursive` shown here - http://book.cakephp.org/view/73/Retrieving-Your-Data. But I would like to direct your attention on the fact that you've got an error on missing foreign key column. That's, probably, because you set the wrong model association (belongsTo).